# Need a breakdown of this sum of two int arrays

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[4] = {7,9,3,4};
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        a[0]+=a[i]+1;
    }
    cout << a[0];
}
```

I ran this code through the compiler and the answer turns out to be 26. Now i'm trying to understand how to arrive at that answer.

I'm pretty sure that the for loop initialization starts with the counter variable 1, the condition is i < 4 which is initially true and the loop will continue to increment i with an output of 1,2,3 until i = 4 and the condition is false.

Now what I don't understand is what happens next in the process. Am I taking index a[0] which is 7 and adding that to "a[i]+1"? If so what is the value of "a[i]+1"?

Comment: That's exactly what is the expected output. 7 + 9 + 3 + 4 + **3** => 26.

Comment: You do understand `a[0] += a[i] + 1;` is done three times with i={1, 2, 3}? It does not happen *"next in the process"*. It is part of the loop.

Comment: "sum of two int arrays" ... where is the second array?? I can only see one, called `a[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing 3 steps:

```
a[0] += a[1] + 1
a[0] += a[2] + 1
a[0] += a[3] + 1
```

i.e.:

```
a[0] = 7 + 9 + 1 = 17
a[0] = 17 + 3 + 1 = 21
a[0] = 21 + 4 + 1 = 26
```

It's giving the sum of the array plus 3, because there are three steps in the computation.

Comment: This answer is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
a[0]+=a[i]+1;
}
```

`a[0]` accumulates values of (including itslef)  `a[1] + 1`, `a[2] + 1`, and `a[3] + 1` respectively according to the changes of the loop variable `i` in each iteration of the loop.

As the initial value of `a[0]` is `7`

```
int a[4] = {7,9,3,4};
```

then you will have

```
7 + ( 9 + 1 ) = 17
17 + ( 3 + 1 ) = 21
21 + ( 4 + 1 ) = 26
```